# Insert into mysql results in duplicate key

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I try to insert some data into a database. 
First I make sure I do have data.
I cannot find the reason, why the data are not inserted.

```
echo 'os_id = ', $os_id, ' os_shoph = ', $os_shoph, ' os_shopd = ',  $os_shopd;

        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT `f2go`.`prints` ("
                    . "prt_os_id, prt_ts, prt_shoph, prt_shopd)"
                    . "VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ? )");

        $insert->bind_param('iss',
                $os_id,
                $os_shoph, 
                $os_shopd); 

        if($insert->execute()) {
            echo '<h1>Print new order ', $os_id, '</h1>';
        } else {
            echo '<h1>Re-print order ', $os_id, '</h1>';
        }      
    }
```

I add error checks.

```
if (!($insert = $db->prepare("INSERT `f2go`.`prints` ("
                        . "prt_os_id, prt_ts, prt_shoph, prt_shopd)"
                        . "VALUES (?, NOW(), ?, ? )"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $db->errno . ") " . $db->error;
}
if (!$insert->bind_param("iss", $os_id, $os_shoph, $os_shopd)) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $insert->errno . ") " . $insert->error;
}
if (!$insert->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $insert->errno . ") " . $insert->error;
}
```

The result is:

```
os_id = "206" os_shoph = 0228099392 os_shopd = example 
Re-print order "206" 
Execute failed: (1062) Duplicate entry '0' for key 'prt_os_id'
```

The database column os_id is set to 'unique'
I cannot figure out why os_id=206 will be seen as '0'

Comment: The os_id seems to have value "206" (with quotes) instead of 206.

Comment: your $os_Id , wherever it came from is a string with exact **5 chars** : `"206"` all chars counts. With a simple echo , if you see **"** in the output means this $os_id contains other chars then numbers.

Comment: I tried echo 'os_id = ', intval($os_id) but that gives me also just 0

Comment: Have you seen my answer ? Not one comment !

Answer (score 0):

you insert 'iss' value in the field 'prt_os_id' and it seems an integer field.
This error 
    Execute failed: (1062) Duplicate entry '0' for key 'prt_os_id'
Refere that insert query put '0' value in the key prt_os_id and when this occur twice this error is displayed, so why '0' value inserted? Because the first value passed in binding is 'iss' and it is string value. It should be:

```
$insert->bind_param("1", $os_id, $os_shoph, $os_shopd))
$insert->bind_param("2", $os_id, $os_shoph, $os_shopd))
$insert->bind_param("3", $os_id, $os_shoph, $os_shopd))
$insert->bind_param("4", $os_id, $os_shoph, $os_shopd))
```

And so on.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: `$insert->bind_param("1",.....))` What are you playing at? That's not **Perl** here.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the quotes from `$os_id` !!

Test it

```
<?php
  $os_id ='"206"';
  echo 'os_id = '.intval($os_id).'<br />';
  $os_id ="206";
  echo 'os_id = '.intval($os_id).'<br />';
  $os_id =206;
  echo 'os_id = '.$os_id.'<br />';
  $os_id ="206";
  echo 'os_id = '.$os_id.'<br />';
  echo '-------------------------------------------------------------------------<br />';
  $os_id ='"206"';
  $os_id =trim($os_id, '"');
  echo 'os_id = '.$os_id;
?>
```

**Output :**

> os_id = 0
>   os_id = 206
>   os_id = 206
>   os_id = 206
>
> ---
>
> os_id = 206